# Bizarre Array Mirroring Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays, both of which get populated by data from a post request.

The purpose of this is so that when alterations are made to the "live" array, they are compared to the "original" array so changes can be spotted.

Here is my post:

```
$('#dialogs').load('views/Products/managePicsDialog.php', function(){
        var imageArray = [];
        var originalImageArray = [];
        $('#managePicsDialog').modal();
        productId = 1;
        $.post(ROOT+'products/fetch-thumbnails', 'pid='+productId, function(data){
            imageArray = originalImageArray = data;
            nextPriority = imageArray.length+1;
            renderImageList(imageArray);
        }, 'json')
...
```

Initially I thought this would be fine, `data` gets put into `imageArray` and `originalImageArray`.

Throughout my code `originalImageArray` doesn't get touched at all, only `imageArray` gets manipulated and changed.

Now when it comes to comparing the arrays, it seems originalImageArray copies imageArray on every change which I do not understand why:

```
function saveChanges(imageArray, originalImageArray)
{
    $.each(originalImageArray, function(i, obj){
        $.each(obj, function(i2, v){
            if(imageArray[i][i2] != v)
            {
                alert('changed') // Never happens
            }
        })
    })
}
```

If I "alert each" both arrays the values are clearly shown to copy each other, even though there is no where in my code that states `originalImageArray = imageArray` except in my `$.post` method which only gets called once when the dialog is opened.

Can anyone solve this for me?

---

The contents of the arrays are objects.

---

Here is the full code to help clarify:

```
$('#productGrid').on('click', '#managePics', function(e){ // When managepics option is clicked
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't go to the hyperlink...
    closeMenu(); // Close the popup menu...
    $('#dialogs').load('views/Products/managePicsDialog.php', function(){
        var imageArray = [];
        var originalImageArray = [];
        $('#managePicsDialog').modal();
        productId = 1;
        $.post(ROOT+'products/fetch-thumbnails', 'pid='+productId, function(data){
            imageArray = data;
            originalImageArray = data.slice(0);
            nextPriority = imageArray.length+1;
            renderImageList(imageArray);
        }, 'json')

        $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
            url: ROOT+'UploadHandler',
            process: [
            {
                maxFileSize: 2000000000 
            }
            ],
            progressInterval: 50,
            add: function(e, data)
            {
                data.submit();
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%').html(progress+'%');
            },
            done: function(e, data)
            {
                n = $.parseJSON(data.result)
                pushed = {
                    "id": "0",
                    "priority": nextPriority,
                    "thumb": n.files[0].thumbnail_url,
                    "deleted": 0
                }
                imageArray.push(pushed);

                renderImageList(imageArray);
            }
        });
        $('#thumbnails').on('click', 'button.delete', function(e){
            $(this).closest('.span8').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $(this).detach();
            });
            idx = $(this).closest('.span8').data('index');
            deleteImage(imageArray, idx)
        })
        $('#managePicsDialog').on('click', '.move-down:not(.disabled)', function(){
            idx = $(this).closest('.span8').data('index');
            if(imageArray[idx+1])
            {
                temp = imageArray[idx+1];
                imageArray[idx+1] = imageArray[idx];
            } else {
                temp = imageArray[0];
                imageArray[0] = imageArray[idx];
            }
            imageArray[idx] = temp;
            renderImageList(imageArray)
        })
        $('#managePicsDialog').on('click', '.move-up:not(.disabled)', function(){
            idx = $(this).closest('.span8').data('index');
            if(imageArray[idx-1])
            {
                temp = imageArray[idx-1];
                imageArray[idx-1] = imageArray[idx];
            } else {
                temp = imageArray[imageArray.length-1];
                imageArray[imageArray.length-1] = imageArray[idx];
            }
            imageArray[idx] = temp;
            renderImageList(imageArray)
        })
        $('#cancelChanges').click(cancelChanges)
        $('#saveChanges').click(function(){
            saveChanges(imageArray, originalImageArray)
        })
    })// Close dialog

})

function saveChanges(imageArray, originalImageArray)
{
   // commitChanges(imageArray)

    $.each(originalImageArray, function(i, obj){
        $.each(obj, function(i2, v){
            alert(i2+' => '+v)
        })
    })
    $.each(imageArray, function(i, obj){
        $.each(obj, function(i2, v){
            alert(i2+' => '+v)
        })
    })

    $.each(originalImageArray, function(i, obj){
        $.each(obj, function(i2, v){
            if(imageArray[i][i2] != v)
            {
                alert('changed')
            }
        })
    })
}
function deleteImage(imageArray, index)
{
    if(imageArray[index].id == 0) // If is a new image we just remove it from array.
    {
        imageArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else { // If existing image we mark it for deletion.
        imageArray[index].deleted = 1;   
    }

    renderImageList(imageArray);
}

function renderImageList(imageArray)
{
    var thumbHTML = '';
    $.each(imageArray, function(i, v){
        if(v.deleted == 0)
        {
            thumbHTML += '<div class="span8 well" data-index="'+i+'">';
            thumbHTML += '<div class="span2">';
            thumbHTML += '<img src="images/'+v.thumb+'" height="" width="" class="last-added">';
            thumbHTML += '</div>';
            thumbHTML += '<div class="span4">';
            thumbHTML += '</div>';
            thumbHTML += '<div class="span1">';
            thumbHTML += '<button class="btn btn-info btn-100 move-up">Move up</button>';
            thumbHTML += '<button class="btn btn-info btn-100 move-down">Move down</button>';
            thumbHTML += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-100 delete">Remove</button>';
            thumbHTML += '</div>';
            thumbHTML += '</div>';
        }
    })
    $('#thumbnails').html(thumbHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to clone it so they do not share the same reference

```
imageArray = data;
originalImageArray = data.slice(0);
```

Comment: @imperium2335 did not work how? Your comment provides zero useful information

Comment: @imperium2335 what are you doing now? An example shows that what I proposed works. http://jsfiddle.net/RHUQy/

Comment: @imperium2335 awesome response. Good luck finding your answer.

Comment: Your issue is probably something else now. I am not going to walk through all of the code. I am willing to bet that your new problem is probably related to the fact you can not really just compare an object to an object. Add some debugging and figure out where it fails.